# I don't know what to call this in English! Constant Value? Lyapunov function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

first of all let me apologise. I am English but I'm studying in Germany and haven't been able to find a translation of what this is called.

I have been given the dynamic system $$\dot{x}=1$$ $$\dot{y}=-y$$ and told to find an *Erhaltungsgröße*. This will be a little difficult to explain because I don't understand it properly (hence being here).
My understanding is that I need to find a function $E(x,y)$ such that for a solution curve $\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}$ $E(x(t), y(t))=const$.

We've been given the starting point that $E(x,y)=X(x)\cdot Y(y)$

I've attempted to solve this (and not come very far) by:
$$0=\frac{d}{dt}E(x(t), y(t))=\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}\dot{x}+ \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}\dot{y}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}E(x,y)=X´(x)\dot{x}+ Y´(y)\dot{y}=X´(x)+Y´(y)(-1)=0$$

I only came to this idea because of a similar problem we were given with the starting point $E(r,v)=R(r)+V(v)$ but I'm unsure if I can apply it here.

So, what is this called in English (so that I can maybe look up some info on it)? And how do I proceed?

Edit: Perhaps a little more explanation may help. Anything which is conserved is an *Erhaltungsgröße* - such as energy.

Edit II: I'm taking Differential Equations for Engineers so we aren't going too deeply into most of these problems. The wiki page for a Lyapunov function seems to be in the right direction but there is also a lot on there I don't recognise or understand.

Comment: A Lyapunov function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function

Comment: seems like it might be. It's certainly related to equilibrium points. We haven't really covered this is either lectures or tutorials hence me being a bit lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I learned it as a "constant of the motion".  As you say, energy of the system is often one, as is angular momentum.  This came in the context of classical mechanics.